# Turing machine that accepts another turing machine if it makes a certain move

Tags: turing-machines

Is it possible to build a [turing-machine](/questions/tagged/turing-machine) that has another [turing-machine](/questions/tagged/turing-machine) and a string as input and accepts if the received machine would make a left or right (or anything) move for that string?

Comment: I think it should be possible by simulating the argument Turing machine on that string and looking at what moves it takes. So if argument TM halts on the string, our halts as well. It's not that different from building a universal Turing Machine.

Comment: Sounds like solving [the halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) to me.

Comment: @GSerg No, it isn't. The halting problem is only a problem because if the emulated program has not halted after time x there is no knowledge gain.

Comment: Well, if it's possible that the received machine doesn't halt instead of making a decision then it's the halting problem, obviously. If the OP means "if the received machine would make a right move instead of something different but finite" then it's not the halting problem since the received machine always halts.

Comment: To the OP: By the above comment I also wanted to say that I found the question somewhat unclear ;-). Care to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Creating such a machine requires solving the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem#Sketch_of_proof).  To show this, assume your input is Turing machine *T*, and I pass it through another machine that modifies every `halt` instruction with `turn left` followed by `halt`.  I then feed this new machine, *T'* into your candidate machine.  In order for your machine to correctly detect whether *T'* will `turn left`, it must solve the halting problem.